# indexOf() only works with a single value in array

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I am filtering a series of HTML items using checkboxes. When I check a single checkbox, everything works fine but if I select multiple, the list displays nothing. I figure that this is something to do with && logic rather than || but I'm not sure where.

```
$('#state-filter input').change(function(){    

    var checkedBoxes = [];

    // Check which checkboxes are checked
    $('#state-filter input').each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            // Push to array
            checkedBoxes.push(this.name);
        }
    });

    console.log(checkedBoxes);
    filterNamesByState();


    function filterNamesByState(){
        // loop through each item
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            let state = items[i].querySelector('.item-state').innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            if(state.indexOf(checkedBoxes) >= 0){
                items[i].style.display = 'flex';
            }else{
                items[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Passing an array to `.indexOf()` won't work the way you think. The array will be converted to a string. You'll have to check each member of the array individually.

Comment: Logic needed also depends on filter rules... match all vs match any. Providing a *runnable* [mcve] will help others help you with a solution. Also define the filtering rules. You can click on `<>` in question editor toolbar to add sample html along with your js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pointy pointed out, `indexOf()` returns a string. I could have used the newish `.includes()` function but for the sake of cross-browser compatibility it was simpler to write my own `isInArray` function.

```
function isInArray(str, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == str) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```